# Why do we have to convert InputStream to ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, android

Why `openInputStream` function doesn't return byte representation of the file instead of returning `InputStream` which we have to iterate through and put it in `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: Why you'd expect a method that *clearly* states it opens an stream to return a full byte representation of the file?

Answer (score 1):

The class InputStream is an abstract class, you cannot have an instance of it.
Most such methods declare to return InputStream but actually return some real/concrete implementation of it. Then you can typically construct a higher-level stream (depending what your needs are) which accepts InputStream in its constructor as parameter.
Now, you need ByteArrayOutputStream but somebody else might need something else as e.g. a FileInputStream. As the method returns InputStream, it can be useful to you both.

Answer (score 1):

An `InputStream` is a different concept than a "byte representation of the file". You can actually get that from the stream, but most likely you don't want to.

A stream is an abstract concept of *a queue of bytes*, and is valid for a lot of things, not just files. By reading from an `InputStream` you're actually reading the file's byte contents, but *one by one* to avoid wasting memory whn reading big files.

What you might be interested in, though, is *memory mapping*. Memory mapping allows you to map a portion of a file (or the whole file) directly into memory, so you can work directly with is.

Read more about Java's memory mapping here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html